# Cannot Edit Excel Document with Full Control Permission

Tags: 2013, permissions, excel

There is a document with permission. User A and User B can only edit the document after they open from sharepoint.

User A has Excel 2013 in his PC. When he opens it in Excel it says "The document is Read-Only..Edit workbook(button)" and on the top-right his username appears. When he push the "Edit Workbook" and edit,than save and close the document, he can see the updated version of it after opening it.

User B has Ecel 2010 in his PC. When he opens there is no message like above and no username of his. He can't update the document.

So how can I make users like User B are able to edit the document?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the url of the sharepoint site where the excel file resides to the trusted zone in Internet explorer (internet options). This needs to be done in the User B workstation.

Check for other similar security settings like firewall policies,anti-virus,etc.